# Custom compare dictionaries linq

Tags: linq, dictionary

I've two dictionaries as following:

Dictionary 1:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();

request.Add("key1", "value1");

request.Add("key2", "value2");    

request.Add("key3", "value3");
```

Dictionary 2 :

```
Dictionary<string, string> request = new Dictionary<string, string>();

request.Add("key1", "value1");

request.Add("key2", "value2");
```

I need to compare above two dictionaries using LINQ query with condition:

1) **All keys in dict2 should match with keys in dict1**

2) **The matched keys should have equivalent value**

3) **Even if the value of key2 in dict2 is empty, it should match**

Help on above in appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Sachin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`Contains` method and provide a custom `IEqualityComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118.aspx), but an easier way would be to use [`Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx):

```
var dict1 = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"key1", "value1"},
    {"key2", "value2"},
    {"key3", "value3"}
};

var dict2 = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"key1", "value1"},
    {"key2", "value2"}
};

dict2.All(k2 => 
        dict1.Any(k1 => k1.Key == k2.Key && 
                        (String.IsNullOrEmpty(k2.Value) || k1.Value == k2.Value)))
```

I guess with *empty* you mean `null` or an empty string, hence I used [`String.IsNullOrEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If you want to just check for `null`, do a simple `k2.Value == null` instead.